# Easy array creation in js or jquery as in python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, arrays

```
myArray = [arr[p2][it] for (it in subarr)]
```

how can we have a similar syntatic sugar like python in javascript or using jquery. I don't want to create an array and push the data

sot that for doing some other calcualtions i can use `.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method for that.

```
let myArray = subarr.map(v => arr[p2][v]);
```

```js
let arr = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 5
  }],
  p2 = 0,
  subarr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

let myArray = subarr.map(v => arr[p2][v]);

console.log(myArray);
```